# Restoring Win server 2008 from full back up?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, dell-poweredge, hardware-raid

I'm having trouble of restoring win server 2008, can anyone help me.

First of all, i got the Power Edge 2900 running raid 1 with 3 disk. Power outage happend, and 2 disks are gone -slot0 and slot1 (both flash yellow led), and controller shows lost configuration, no VD configuration found.

Then I changed the survive disk to slot0, plugin into slot1 a new disk, clear foreign, create new raid 1 (no init) and let the background init running. After 12 hours, all shows online, no error, but server stop at "strike f1 to continue, f2 to...", it wont boot into windows.

I got the full server backup image, so i removed both disk, install 2 new disk, create new raid, fast init, trying to do a full system restore using a boot USB created by rufus (newest version). When it came to the selection "choose system image to restore", i got the msg: "To restore this computer Windows needs to format the drive that the Windows Recovery environment is currently running on"

What i used to restore: usb boot, an external hdd with the windows image.

What i tried:

- Using diskpart to format the drive, same error
- Using format utilizi from the installation itself, same
- Install new win 2008 and try restore from the boot USB again, same
- Creating new System recovery USB by Windows 7 USB/DVD download tool but got the error: not compatible USB to select.

I'm almost as dead end, any advice would be very appreciated, thank you.

I just need a way to get the pc on again, it is a DC, either by system restore, or by rebuilding the raid, still have 1 disk working the in the old raid (slot2 as described) intact.

Comment: Are you sure that your recovery environment USB drive contains drivers for your RAID controller? Looks like it does not see your storage and tries to restore to the only available USB device.

Comment: Im not sure about that, but by using that USB boot, i can install the new version of windows on that pc, so it wouldnt be a problem of drivers right?

Comment: The new system disk still a MBR disk, right? Not that someone choose bigger disks and initializes a GPT drive, which was not supported (invented) in Server 2008 ...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the server back by restoring from my image using DVD. Tried alot of way using USB boot but jumped into errors after errors.
So for anyone jumps into my situation, this is what I do:

- Create CD boot from your windows version iso. Always keep a version of CD boot by your side.
- Remove all USB from your server, only plug-in your external hdd containing the image after your setup shows "found no image to restore"

Just like that and continue with normal restoring process, took me whole 2 days.